# Next-seo metadata is not getting overrided

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm using Next.js 13 with a page directory structure. In my project, I've set up a `DefaultSeo` tag in `_app.tsx` to manage global SEO settings. Additionally, in one of my pages, I'm utilizing the `NextSeo` tag to dynamically set metadata using `getServerSideProps`.

Despite successfully overriding the default Open Graph values (title, description, image) in the specific page, social media platforms consistently display the default values when I attempt to share the page link.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Set up Next.js 13.4.6 with a page directory structure.
2. Implement a `DefaultSeo` tag in `_app.tsx` for global SEO settings.
3. Include a `NextSeo` tag in a specific page to dynamically set metadata using `getServerSideProps`.
4. Attempt to share the page link on various social media platforms.
5. Observe that the shared previews consistently display the default Open Graph values, ignoring the overridden values specified in the `NextSeo` tag.

**Additional Note:**

One important note is that the dynamic metadata can be inspected in HTML, but it briefly flashes the default values for a fraction of a second before falling back to using the overridden values. However, this behavior is not reflected when sharing a link on social media platforms.

**Code Snippets:**

`/_app.tsx`

```
const defaultSeoConfig: DefaultSeoProps = {
  title: 'default title',
  description: 'default description',
  additionalLinkTags: [
    {
      rel: 'icon',
      href: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/favicon.png}`,
    },
  ],
  openGraph: {
    type: 'website',
    locale: 'en_IE',
    url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/`,
  },
  twitter: {
    handle: '@site',
    site: '@site',
    cardType: 'summary_large_image',
  },
};

<DefaultSeo
    title={defaultSeoConfig.title}
    description={defaultSeoConfig.description}
    openGraph={defaultSeoConfig.openGraph}
    twitter={defaultSeoConfig.twitter}
  />
```

`/pages/myPage`

```
<NextSeo
  title={` ${countryDetails.name}`}
  openGraph={{
    url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}${nextRouter.asPath}`,
    images: [
      {
        url: countryDetails.images[0].file || OG_TAG_IMAGE,
      },
    ],
  }}
/>
```